# Inserting data from one table to another | mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm currently learning vb.net and I'm working on a little test project. Thing is, I have five tables:

Login, where I keep login information for students:

```
IDUser | Name | Surname | Username   | Password
---------------------------------------------
1      | John | Smith   | john.smith | john123
```

Students, where I keep basic informations about students

```
IDStudent | Name | Surname
--------------------------
1         | John | Smith
```

Professors, where I keep basic informations about professors

```
IDProfessor | Name | Surname 
----------------------------
1           | Mike | Petersen
```

Subjects, where I keep basic information about subjects

```
IDSubject | SubjectName | ProfessorName
---------------------------------------
1         | Programming | Gary Williams
```

and for a final table, in which I need to insert data from tables above, I have Courses:

```
IDCourse | StudentID | SubjectID | ProfessorID
----------------------------------------------
1        | ??        | ???       | ????
```

The question is, how do I insert data in Course table from tables above. I'm currently using MySql as my database, and I've created foreign keys and connected them with the primary keys. I also have a ComboBox (filled with subjects from Subjects table) where a student can choose a Subject and by pressing the button, insert it in a Courses table.

Comment: As an aside, you need to have another look at normalising your db design. You have duplicated data between tables login and students, and subjects and professors.

Comment: As far as saving passwords, this is fine for a test project with no real logins but for a real world application, you would never store passwords as plain text.

Comment: To expand a bit on what peterG said. Combine the Students table and the login table. In the Subjects table change ProfessorName to a foreign key ProfessorID. Suppose you had a professor Mary Jones and she gets married so now she is Mary Smith. You would have to go through and change every instance in the Subjects table to the new name. With the foreign key you would only have to change it once in the Professors table and all would be well.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'm still new to all of this but glad you pointed out the right way to learn.

Comment: See my updated answer and upvote it if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DataTable`s for each table and insert table data from one to another.For example :

```
 Dim con as new MySqlConnection="connectionsstringhere"
 con.open
 Dim cmd as new Mysqlcommand = "Select * from Login",con)

 dim table as new datatable
 Dim adapter as new mysqldataadapter(cmd)
 adapter.filll(table)
 Dim cmd2 as new mysqlcommand("Insert into Courses([student id],[subject id],[Professor id])values(@sid,@sbid,@pid)",con)
 cmd2.parametres.add("@sid",mysqldbtype.nvarchar).Value = table.rows(0)(1)  'here (0) is the column no. and (1) is the cell no.

   cmd2.parametres.add("@sbid",mysqldbtype. nvarchar).Value = table.rows(0)(2)  
 cmd2.executenonquery
 con.close
```

The following code will insert  `Login` table's first 2 cells' data in `Courses` table.

**Note that this is just a basic example.You need to modify the code based on your requirements**

**UPDATE**
I must've added this yesterday but i was a bit busy...However let's begin....

For each column in each tables,you can create a `list(of string)`.For example,create a `list(of string)` sub/variable named `StudentnameandID`.. Now, use a `datatable` for the first two tables(Student and Professor).Pass the values of cell 1 from the datatable to the List(of string) sub `STUDENTNAMEANDID`Make sure you add a special character like a comma(,) after every value...Then finally you can separate each value from `Studentnameandid`aas you've added commas... Then `for each` value in `Studentnameandid`, you add data to your last table.....

**If you want a sample code for this,leave a comment and i'll add it**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already found a different solution. But this will help me in my learning process. Thanks again!

Comment: What is the differenr solution??